# Spring Cloud Data Flow Management with SSL

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Unable to **access management end point** once local spring cloud data flow server is **ssl enabled and has basic authentication**

I have **docker-compose.yml** file that can start dataflow server with ssl and file based authentication, this works, I am able to now run dataflow server on port 8443 and access the dashboard by supplying the correct credentials.

```
  env_file:
      - .env
  dataflow-server:
    image: repo.mitchell.com/springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local:${DATAFLOW_VERSION}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
      - "9900:9900"
      - "8443:8443"
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers=kafka:9092
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.applicationProperties.stream.spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.zkNodes=zookeeper:2181
      - spring_datasource_url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow
      - spring_datasource_username=root
      - spring_datasource_password=${MYSQL_PASS}
      - spring_datasource_driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.metrics.collector.uri=${METRICS_COLLECTOR_URI}:8080
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.metrics.collector.username=${METRICS_COLLECTOR_USER}
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.metrics.collector.password=${METRICS_COLLECTOR_PASS}
      - server.port=8443
      - server.ssl.enabled=true
      - server.ssl.key-store=${SSL_KEY_STORE_PATH}
      - server.ssl.key-store-password=${SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASS}
      - server.ssl.keyStoreType=JKS
      - server.ssl.keyAlias=${SSL_KEY_ALIAS}
      - security.require-ssl=true
      - server.ssl.trust-store=${SSL_TRUST_STORE_PATH}
      - server.ssl.trust-store-password=${SSL_TRUST_STORE_PASS}
      - management.security.enabled=true
      - management.context-path=/management
      - security.basic.enabled=true
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.file.enabled=true
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.file.users.bob=bobpass, ROLE_MANAGE
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.file.users.${FILE_AUTH_ADMIN_USER}=${FILE_AUTH_ADMIN_PASS}, ROLE_VIEW, ROLE_CREATE, ROLE_MANAGE
      - spring.cloud.dataflow.security.authentication.file.users.${FILE_AUTH_USER}=${FILE_AUTH_PASS}, ROLE_VIEW
```

I expect that `https://<ipaddress>:8443/management` is accessible, however it keeps redirectin to `https://<ipaddress>:8443/dashboard/#/apps`

Comment: If I expose port 8081:8081 and try this    - management.port=8081 , - management.ssl.enabled=false, - management.security.enabled=false then I get a different error when I access http://<ipaddress>:8081/management

Comment: The error is  2019-01-25 01:41:01.957  INFO 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-4] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
dataflow-server      |  Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
dataflow-server      |
dataflow-server      | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation (by design) of having UI and RestEndpoints under the same root. Therefore, if you hit the server with a browser, we by default serve the UI and redirect to `/dashboard`

If you use command-line tools such as `curl`, the JSON REST response is served, e.g.:

```sh
curl -X GET -k -i https://localhost:8443/management -u user:secret_password
```

When using a browser, I would recommend using [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop/related?hl=en) (Chrome) or [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/) (Firefox).

Comment: Nice. I cloned the source, and did see that index.html has base ref pointing '/' one another reason why we can put this behind a dyanmic load balancer with route specification such zuul that expects non root context-path. Can be changed, but then will have to reimage etc.

Comment: If you could just mark the question as resolved that would be awesome - THANKS! :-)